# Using group by and order by to fetch top row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 rows released,major,minor. I want to pick the latest version in every release. I want to get 6_9_8,4_0_2,3_4_3 which are the latest version in that release.

I tried the below query but it returns everything.

`select releaseId,major,minor from release_table group by releaseId  order by major desc,minor desc`

| releaseId | major | minor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 9 | 8 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

```
with p as (
select rowid=row_number() over (partition by releaseid order by major desc, minor desc),
*
from mytable
)
select releaseid, major, minor
from p 
where rowid=1
```